# Rsyslog - send logs to remote server

Tags: logs, rename, syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to send service log files to a centralized Rsyslog server.

On the Syslog server, I have a simple configuration

```
$template DailyPerHostLogs,"/var/log/syslog/%$DAY%/%Fromhost-ip%/%syslogfacility-text%.log"
*.* -?DailyPerHostLogs
```

on the client-server I did that configuration :

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 5
$InputFileName /var/log/aide/*.log
$InputFileTag AIDE:
$InputFileStateFile state-aide-log
$InputFileFacility local5
$InputRunFileMonitor


local5.*          @IP-ADDRESS
```

Now, it sends files to the remote server, but the context is deformed. for example, there are few lines on the client :

```
Total number of files:        32567
Added files:                  0
Removed files:                0
Changed files:                1
```

but on the Syslog-server :

```
Mar 26 12:16:16 *** AIDE:  Total number of files:#01132567
Mar 26 12:16:16 *** AIDE:  Added files:#011#011#0110
Mar 26 12:16:16 *** AIDE:  Removed files:#011#0110
Mar 26 12:16:16 *** AIDE:  Changed files:#011#0111
```

Also, the name of the file on the remote-server is local5.log

How can I send files without context change and with the original name??

Comment: Just nitpick, rsyslog syntax has been changing couple of times and you use *obsolete legacy directives*. See https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#configuration-examples Try to check with `tcpdump` if arriving data are same as on source.

Comment: I really dislike rsyslog because of its 3 supported formats and still because of multiple ways to write "rules" in advanced format. Maybe if you would like to make your life easier and your syntax more consitent check https://vector.dev/. Or syslog-ng would be still better alternative than rsyslog.